# When using toupper() function, it outputs the ASCII value. Why is that, and how do I make it just print the character?

Tags: c++, function

When using toupper() function, it outputs the ASCII value. Why is that, and how do I make it just print the character?
Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cctype>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {   char ch1 = 'H';
        char ch2 = 'e';
        char ch3 = '!';
        cout << toupper(ch1); // displays 'H'
        cout << toupper(ch2); // displays 'E'
        cout << toupper(ch3); // displays '!'
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `toupper` returns an `int`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper If you want to print the return value as a `char` you'll need to cast it or assign it to a `char` variable and then print that..

Comment: For what it's worth: my search was for "[c++] toupper ascii". The top three hits were a duplicate of the proposed duplicate, this question, and the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Pay special attention to [the Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper#Notes). `tolower` also takes an `int` as its parameter and this can lead to weird results.